# Integrate $\int \frac{(x+1)}{(x^2+2)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is the question I want to ask

Integrate $$\int \frac{(x+1)}{(x^2+2)^2}\,dx.$$
 I tried it using algebric manipulation
Integrate $x/(x^2+2)^2+1/(x^2+2)^2$.
Then the latter part would not be solved.

Comment: Hint: try to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2}$ by parts

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$x=\sqrt2\tan y\implies $

$$\int \frac{(x+1)}{(x^2+2)^2}\,dx=\int\dfrac{\sqrt2\tan y+1}{(2\sec^2y)^2}\cdot\sqrt2\sec^2y\ dy$$

$$=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\int(\sqrt2\sin y\cos y+\cos^2y)dy$$

$$=\dfrac1{4\sqrt2}\int(\sqrt2\sin2y+1+\cos2y)dy$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks alot!!

Answer (score 2):

We split the integral into two components as

$$\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx=\int\frac{x}{(x^2+2)^2}dx+\int\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx\tag 1$$

---

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is trivial to evaluate using the substitution $x^2=u\implies x\,dx\to \frac12 du$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{x}{(x^2+2)^2}dx&=\frac12\int  \frac{1}{(u+2)^2}\,du\\\\
&=-\frac12 \frac{1}{u+2}\\\\
&=-\frac12 \frac{1}{x^2+2} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

For the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ , we use the classical trigonometric substitution $x=\sqrt{2}\tan \theta\implies dx=\sqrt{2}\sec^2 \theta d\theta$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\int  \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\sec^4 \theta}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\int  \cos^2 \theta \,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\int  \left(\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}\right) \,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \left(\theta +\frac12 \sin 2\theta\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \left(\theta + \sin \theta \cos \theta \right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \left(\arctan(x/\sqrt{2}) + \frac{\sqrt{2}x}{x^2+2} \right) \tag 3\\\\
\end{align}$$

---

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} \arctan(x/\sqrt{2})+\frac14 \frac{x-2}{x^2+2}+C}$$

Comment: You are too fast for an old man ! I am happy to see that you probably recovered (obviously, the brain is OK) !! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hey my friend!  Well, I am still on the wound vac device, 24 x 7, but hopeful that next week will be the last.  As for the brain, well, I am not too far behind you in years.  So, it keeps slipping too.  ;-)))

Comment: All my best best best wishes. If I may ask, how old are you and what are you doing ? Your profile is quite short !

Comment: Ok for me (hoping that I shall be able to join it - I had several times problems with that). So, open the chat room and tell me how I need to process. See you soon (I hope).

Comment: @user255410 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The latter part can be computed by integrating by parts:
$$
\int \frac1{x^2+2}\,dx=\int \frac{x^2+2}{(x^2+2)^2}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+2)^2}\,dx=\int \frac{2x}{(x^2+2)^2}\cdot\frac12x\,dx.
$$
The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx$$

Let $x=\sqrt{2}\tan \theta\;,$ Then $dx = \sqrt{2}\sec^2 \theta d\theta$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{\sqrt{2}\sec^2 \theta }{4\sec^4 \theta }d\theta = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int \cos ^2\theta d\theta = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\int (1+\cos 2 \theta )d\theta$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(\theta +\frac{\sin 2\theta }{2}\right)+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}x}{x^2+2}+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int \frac{1}{(x^2+2)^2}dx = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{x}{x^2+2}+\mathcal{C}$$